# Getting a unique object from a indexedDB in Dart

Tags: dart, indexeddb

I'm trying to get information from an `indexedDB`, and I want to get just the object from one store by key, and not all the objects from the database. In some examples of `javascript` and `IndexedDB` they use the method `get()` to get the value depending of the key. In DART there is not such method but there is `getObject()`.

How do I get the value of the object when using `getObject(key)`?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you take a look at the [LawnDart](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/lawndart) project?

Comment: In fact, as I had the same problem with LawnDart I came back to the old way. My problem is not getting the object itself but the information in it. That by the way, It's a Map. Thanks Günter !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it has `getObject(key)` method, take a look here https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-dom-indexed_db.ObjectStore@id_getObject

The other way for fetching data is `Cursor`. Here is a good tutorial https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/indexeddb/#getting-data

Comment: I now, but getObject() retrieves a Future and I am not capable to take that Future's value, surely because I'm doing something wrong. I've worked with cursor and at least I get the value. Thanks Nikis for the help and formating !

Comment: Here is a good answer how to use `Future` object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681034/indexed-db-getobject-how-to-return-result

Answer (score 0):

So all needed to do was to create a callback. This is how I got the objects value:

```dart
var id = "example";
var trans = _db.transaction('myDB', 'readwrite');
var store = trans.objectStore(_TODOS_STORE);

// Get the value from one object ! and render it 

var request = store.getObject(id).then((val){functionFor(val);});
```

Futures need from callbacks to be able to use their values.