# Using the IndexedDb ObjectStore in Dart

Tags: dart, indexeddb, dart-html

I've been trying to get a single entry from an IndexedDb instance using Dart's IndexedDb package. But I call `getObject()` which the documentation says returns a `Future`* (a Future of what I don't know) I don't have any `Maps` or other objects to work with.

What does the `Future` return in the `store.getObject(id).then()` method? If it doesn't return anything, how do I get information stored in the DB?

```dart
//within a TurnObjectStore class
Future<Turn> getTurn(int id){
    Transaction t = _db.transaction(_TABLE_NAME, 'readonly');
    ObjectStore store = t.objectStore(_TABLE_NAME);
    return store.getObject(id).then((Map turn){
        print('getTurn');
        print(turn);
        return turn;
    });
}
```

A similar question is answered here [indexed_db getObject() - how to return result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681034/indexed-db-getobject-how-to-return-result) but I'm getting warnings in my IDE when I try it that way and I'm wondering if the spec has changed since last year.

- https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-indexed_db.ObjectStore#id_getObject

Answer (score 1):

I am using Dart 1.2 and **getObject(id)** works fine.

I believe that the returned *Future* type depends on what is stored into your DB...
If you did save the data as a *Map* of your object, it will return a *Map*.

To **store&restore** your object as a *Map*, you can look at [the official dart example for indexedDB](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-tutorials-samples/tree/master/web/count_down):

```dart
// Serialize this to an object (a Map) to insert into the database.
Map toRaw() {
   return {
     'milestoneName': milestoneName,
     'happensOn': happensOn.toString(),
   };
}

//Create a Milestone based on the Map returned by the IndexedDB
 Milestone.fromRaw(key, Map value):
  dbKey = key,
  milestoneName = value['milestoneName'],
  happensOn = DateTime.parse(value['happensOn']) {
  tick();
  }
```

You can see the stored object directly from the developers tools of chrome, for a stored Map it should looks like this:

[image]

So i can get back the object with getObject:

```dart
var tr = mydb.transaction(myDB.CLIENT_STORE, 'readonly');
var st = tr.objectStore(myDB.CLIENT_STORE);
st.getObject(2).then((r){
    Client client = new Client.fromRaw(2,r);
    [...]
}
```